# How to vectorize text in order to use it as feature for time series prediction? (Keras)

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, time-series, word-embedding

What is the best way to vectorize text in order to use it as one of many features for time series prediction?

The time series is daily and I have 8 to 10 different news headlines per date (~16,000 headlines in total). Each headline consists of max 25 words. The headlines are cleaned (lower case, punctuation and number removal, stop word removal and lemmatized) and tokenized on a word level.

How can I vectorize the headlines and aggregate them on a daily level so that I can use them as an input feature? Because all other features (e.g. Federal Funds Rate, Gold Price, etc.) are just a single integer per date.

I thought of using word embeddings. But training a word embedding model (word2vec or GloVe) on only 16,000 headlines probably won’t achieve good results. However, even if I use pre-trained word vectors I am worried about the column dimensionality of my time series data frame in R. Since the word vector is 100 dimensional and I have 25 words per headline and 8-10 headlines per date, the dimension of my time series would be 100x25x10 = 25,000 columns and 1,700 rows (1,700 days).

So do you have any idees of how I can include the news headlines as a feature for time series prediction? If it helps, I plan to implement a LSTM Neural Network in Keras using R for predicting the trend (up or down) of a traded asset.

Ideas and advice are much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an LSTM to learn low-dimensional sentence embeddings, treating each headline as a sequence of vectors and resulting in a more condensed feature-space per headline. Then you can use these abstract features of each headline as input features for a second LSTM that now learns temporal features over dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can train your own model for low dimensional word embeddings. Once these word embeddings are learnt. You can pass it to the next LSTM along with the other input features.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it is quite similar to what @KonstantinosKokus proposed. However, I have a couple of open questions: 

1. What dimension for the self trained word vectors do you suggest? Would 10 dimensional be appropriate in my case?
2. How exactly do I pass the word vectors with the other features to the second LSTM? Of course the original structure implicitly has to stay the same (10 headlines + x integer features per date). Would you mind sharing a pseudo code or R code example using Keras? Only that the structure gets clear? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I am not really sure if 10-dimensional feature space would work for you or not. Maybe you should try using cross-validation for this purpose and select whichever dimension performs best for you. 
For the pseudo code part, I don't really have anything ready to share with you right now, but general idea to connect both the network is: 
1. Try to build first LSTM similar to Glove or Word-2-vec. The dimension of the hidden layer should be the desired dimension of your word embeddings. 
2. Once the above LSTM is trained to a certain accuracy, you start training your 2nd LSTM.

Comment: For this 2nd LSTM, you take your headline first pass it to the previously trained LSTM and instead of retrieving the output you just output the values from the last hidden layer which is the representation of your headline in word embedding space.  Now concatenate these news values with your other features and pass it to the 2nd LSTM.